# Install Ubuntu on second hard drive without CD/DVD

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu but I don't have a CD/DVD burner or large flash drive. I do have access to a second computer and I've hooked up the hard drive to it. How can I install Ubuntu on that hard drive? It seems that this should be easy but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: What OS is the second PC running?

Comment: @the_Seppi: Windows Vista. It has a CD/DVD drive but no burner.

Comment: What's the largest USB stick you have available?

Comment: @the_Seppi: 1 GB? I Was hoping to be able to install from the other hard drive.

Comment: And how big is your Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: @the_Seppi: 981 MB. The flash drive could hold the ISO but I don't think it could hold the uncompressed contents.

Comment: Have you thought about external dvd/cd burner?  There's pretty decent ones in $15 -20 range.  Also look up lubuntu/Xubuntu. Their iso images should be smaller. Also "minimalistic" Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out some way which might work for you:

On your Vista computer:

1. Download and install [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
2. Download a [Super GRUB2 Disk ISO](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) file. Choose [coreboot] if you aren't sure which ISO you need.
3. Install the SG2D ISO to your 1GB USB stick usign UNetBootin.
4. Put the Ubuntu ISO in the root of your USB drive, so you can find it easily afterwards.
5. Edit the file `(usb stick)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
6. Paste the following at the end of the file:

   ```
   menuentry "Ubuntu ISO" {
       iso_path=/ubuntu.iso #Replace with ISO name
       export iso_path
       search --set --file $iso_path
       loopback loop $iso_path
       root=(loop)
       configfile /boot/grub/loopback.cfg
       loopback --delete loop
   }
   ```
7. Save and eject the USB stick.

On your installation machine (With reinserted HDD):

1. Boot from USB stick.
2. You should see the menu option "Ubuntu ISO" in the appearing menu.
3. Select it and ensure it boots (Try without installing)
4. Install Ubuntu on the HDD.

Comment: This way should enable an installation directly on the inteded machine - I edited it likewise.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

1. Disconnect HDD that has Vista
2. Connect the second HDD
3. Install Ubuntu on second HDD
4. Re-Connect HDD to original PC

If this doesn't work, you can burn the CD image to the HDD using Lili (LinuxLive USB Creator) and use it as a live system with persistence. This will allow you to save files, installed packages, etc.

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download

Comment: How does step #3 work? Where is Ubuntu being installed from?

Comment: In the first scenario you will need the installer CD, or you could burn the ubuntu image to the 1GB flash drive you have using Lili.